# Rails Assets Not Compiling In Production But Compiling In Development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, digital-ocean, uglifyjs

I am running ruby 2.4.0 and rails 5 with uglifier >=1.3. My code works locally and will compile in development mode. But when I try to deploy it to DigitalOcean with Capistrano I get an error with precompiling assets.

Here is the error reproduced locally:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:clean assets:precompile
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (parent)
JS_Parse_Error.Object.defineProperty.get ((execjs):3538:621)
```

any ideas?
Here is the output of the assets:precompile in production.

```
** Invoke assets:precompile (first_time)
** Invoke assets:environment (first_time)
** Execute assets:environment
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute assets:precompile
rake aborted!
ExecJS::RuntimeError: SyntaxError: Unexpected token: name (parent)
JS_Parse_Error.Object.defineProperty.get ((execjs):3538:621)
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:47:in `rescue in block in call'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:44:in `block in call'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `Locker'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `lock'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43:in `call'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:195:in `run_uglifyjs'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:157:in `compile'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
V8::Error: Unexpected token: name (parent)
at js_error (<eval>:3623:12181)
at croak (<eval>:3623:21897)
at token_error (<eval>:3623:22034)
at unexpected (<eval>:3623:22122)
at semicolon (<eval>:3623:22614)
at simple_statement (<eval>:3623:25718)
at <eval>:3623:23580
at <eval>:3623:22787
at block_ (<eval>:3623:27800)
at ctor.body (<eval>:3623:27403)
at function_ (<eval>:3623:27499)
at expr_atom (<eval>:3623:30759)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3624:1514)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3624:2322)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3624:2414)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3624:2815)
at expression (<eval>:3624:3128)
at expr_list (<eval>:3623:31239)
at subscripts (<eval>:3624:1223)
at subscripts (<eval>:3624:859)
at subscripts (<eval>:3624:1165)
at expr_atom (<eval>:3623:30896)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3624:1514)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3624:2322)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3624:2414)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3624:2815)
at expression (<eval>:3624:3128)
at simple_statement (<eval>:3623:25701)
at <eval>:3623:23580
at <eval>:3623:22787
at block_ (<eval>:3623:27800)
at ctor.body (<eval>:3623:27403)
at function_ (<eval>:3623:27499)
at expr_atom (<eval>:3623:30759)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3624:1514)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3624:2322)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3624:2414)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3624:2815)
at expression (<eval>:3624:3128)
at expr_list (<eval>:3623:31239)
at subscripts (<eval>:3624:1223)
at subscripts (<eval>:3624:859)
at subscripts (<eval>:3624:1165)
at expr_atom (<eval>:3623:30896)
at maybe_unary (<eval>:3624:1514)
at expr_ops (<eval>:3624:2322)
at maybe_conditional (<eval>:3624:2414)
at maybe_assign (<eval>:3624:2815)
at expression (<eval>:3624:3128)
at simple_statement (<eval>:3623:25701)
at <eval>:3623:23580
at <eval>:3623:22787
at <eval>:3624:3503
at parse (<eval>:3624:3743)
at parse (<eval>:3959:22)
at uglifier (<eval>:4007:13)
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:45:in `block in call'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:75:in `block in lock'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `Locker'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:73:in `lock'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/execjs-2.7.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:43:in `call'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:195:in `run_uglifyjs'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/uglifier-3.2.0/lib/uglifier.rb:157:in `compile'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:53:in `call'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/uglifier_compressor.rb:28:in `call'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:75:in `call_processor'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:57:in `block in call_processors'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `reverse_each'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/processor_utils.rb:56:in `call_processors'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:134:in `load_from_unloaded'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:60:in `block in load'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:317:in `fetch_asset_from_dependency_cache'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/loader.rb:44:in `load'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:20:in `block in initialize'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/cached_environment.rb:47:in `load'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:66:in `find_asset'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/base.rb:73:in `find_all_linked_assets'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:142:in `block in find'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:114:in `block (2 levels) in logical_paths'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:228:in `block in stat_tree'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:212:in `block in stat_directory'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `each'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:209:in `stat_directory'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/path_utils.rb:227:in `stat_tree'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `each'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:105:in `block in logical_paths'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `each'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/legacy.rb:104:in `logical_paths'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:140:in `find'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:185:in `compile'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:68:in `block (3 levels) in define'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-3.7.1/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:147:in `with_logger'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/gems/sprockets-rails-3.2.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:67:in `block (2 levels) in define'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `block in execute'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `each'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:250:in `execute'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:194:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.0/lib/ruby/2.4.0/monitor.rb:214:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:187:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/task.rb:180:in `invoke'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:152:in `invoke_task'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `each'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:108:in `block in top_level'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:117:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:102:in `top_level'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `block in run'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:178:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `run'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0@global/gems/rake-12.0.0/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `load'
/Users/Joseph/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.0/bin/rake:22:in `<main>'
```

Comment: output of `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile --trace`? Have heard about ES6 causing such issues. what is sprockets' version?

Comment: I have been reading about it. Before I posted this, I removed the gems that I thought could be ES6 including Bootstrap 4 and JQuery3.

Comment: I posted the output if that helps @kiddorails.

Comment: try updating to new sprockets version `gem 'sprockets', '4.0.0.beta5'` and run the compilation again. Will help you to figure out if es6 is indeed the issue with sprockets

Comment: Can you narrow down which JS file is causing the problem by taking files out and re-running the compile? A binary search approach would probably be fastest - i.e. remove half the files, test the compile, remove half the remaining files if the compile still fails, etc.

Comment: @Brian - seems like a good approach. Would I just delete JS files from my application.js or remove files in the tree?

Comment: I do have one file that is a js.erb file - would that be problematic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out my JS was not perfectly clean. I had some code let parent... whereas it should have been var parent.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Best strategy is remove JS files one by one to narrow where the problem is occurring. Cheers @brian.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the below line to your Gemfile:

```
group :assets do
 gem 'uglifier'
end
```

Move that gem out of assets group

Comment: Same error - I had gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' installed.

Comment: Did you remove gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' from other group and put in on :assets group? Try run bundle install and bundle update before deploy

Comment: yes - i removed the gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0' before trying. No success.